# roc curve from SVM classifier is visualise with limite thresholds in Python

Tags: classification, svm, roc, auc

i am trying to plot ROC to evaluate my classifier, however my ruc plot is not "smooth". It supposed to be some problem with the thresholds? i am quite new in python classification so propably there is sth wrong with my code. see image below. Where i sould look for solution?

[image: 1]

i used that drop_intermediate=False but it does not help;/

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are passing 0 and 1 values (**predicted labels**) to the plotting function. The ROC curve can only be figured out, when you provide floats in a range of 0.0 to 1.0 (**predicted label probabilities**) such that the ROC curve can consider multiple cutoff values and appears more "smooth" as a result.

Whatever classifier you are using, make sure y_train_pred contains float values in the range [0.0,1.0]. If you have a scoring classifier with values in the range [-∞,+∞] you can apply a [sigmoid function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) to remap the values to this range.